# Issue while using Github Copilot Chat in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Following is the error log that I see but not sure why its failing. Tried options like VPN/non-VPN, uninstall/install, upgrade/downgrade but couldn't resolve it.

```
INFO] [default] [2024-02-28T12:23:39.651Z] request.response: [https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/chat/completions] took 22 ms
[ERROR] [chat fetch] [2024-02-28T12:23:39.655Z] Unhandled status from server:,404,404 page not found
```

Tried options like VPN/non-VPN, uninstall/install, upgrade/downgrade but couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Got resolved after upgrading VS Code to latest version

Comment: Please add some details what "while using" means, that can help the readers how have a similar problem. Please also mark the question as answered, according to your comment.